# Wagtail generic gallery implementation and OneToOneField

Tags: wagtail

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/getting_started/tutorial.html

The wagtail getting_started tutorial intros a blog gallery feature, implements as below:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    ...

class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable)
    page = ParentalKey(BlogPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = ...
```

This way works, however BlogPageGalleryImage couples with BlogPage model. My intention is to make a generic gallery model which can be embbed with any model(page). The idea is using an intermediate Gallery model:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ...

class Gallery(Page):
    pass

class GalleryImage(Orderable):
    gallery = ParentalKey(Gallery, related_name='images')
```

Then in code, we can get the images via `blog.gallery.images`.

My question is how to get it work with wagtail admin interface to inline create/edit the gallery object (OneToOneField) when editing the blog page object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is via a more generic relationship for your Page-Image connection, relating this to the Page model, rather than a specific BlogPage model.

This means that any page can have gallery images, you just need to expose the field to content panels via an `InlinePanel`.

You can also create a Mixin class to make some helpful methods available without rewriting them each time.

Here is an example:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import InlinePanel
from wagtail.core.models import Orderable, Page
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel

class ImageGalleryRelationship(Orderable, models.Model):
    """ Relationship between any `Page` and `Image` for an image gallery."""
    page = ParentalKey(Page, related_name='gallery_page')
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', related_name='gallery_image')
    panels = [ImageChooserPanel('image')]


class PageGalleryMixin():
    def gallery_images(self):
        images = [g.image for g in self.gallery_page.all()]
        return images

class BlogPage(Page, PageGalleryMixin):
    # all page fields, gallery does not need to be defined here
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel('gallery_page', label='Image Gallery'),
        #...
    ]
```

Note: This is not a OneToOne connection, InlinePanel requires a ParentalKey relationship. There is no real 'Gallery' model in this solution just a set of orderable relationships.

Comment: The OO approach works, through one page limited to have only one galley.

Answer (score 0):

In general app (or wherever), models.py

```py
class PageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(Page,
                       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                       related_name='image_gallery')
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='page_gallery_image')
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

Other apps as blog, models.py:

```py
class BlogPage(Page):
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ...
        InlinePanel('image_gallery', label="Gallery images"),
    ]
```

This provides one app = one gallery.